# How can I configure standardised indentation using JsHint and the wro4j plugin?

Tags: maven, plugins, jshint, wro4j

I would like to force 4 spaces as the default and required indentation for my whole js codebase.

I have managed to the [jshint wro4j plugin](http://web-resource-optimization.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/build-time-javascript-code-analysis.html) to work and obey options:

```
<options>browser,newcap,noarg,nonew,undef,trailing</options>
```

However, for indentation, I need to specify the spaces required:

```
/*jshint indent:4 */
```

but there appears to be no facility to do this?

I'm not sure how I should be applying this option correctly as any of the layouts I've tried throw errors as being invalid options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the indentation rule check by adding the following rules:

```
<option>indent,white</option>
```

By default the indentation is set to 4 characters. If you want to set a different value, use this:

```
<option>indent=2,white</option>
```

Comment: Thanks for that I didn't realise I needed to also specify 'white'.  Also, I found it necessary to include 'indent=4' for the system to force 4 spaces (leaving as just 'indent' behaved as though I'd written 'indent=1').  In conclusion 'indent=4,white' worked a treat, thanks!